# Уничтожение сессии при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Есть функция для уничтожения сессии на php. Как выполнить ее по нажатию кнопки?

```
function dstroy(){
    session_destroy();
}
```

Comment: Типа <input type ...

Comment: С помощью ajax запроса вызываете скрипт с нужной вам функциональностью

Comment: Попробую, спасибо

Comment: @Ytn или с помощью post | get запроса _(если на php)_ передавать на сервер некую переменную, и по её наличию вызывать функцию.

Comment: Не забывайте, что для применения данных сессии нужно обновить страницу, то есть заново получить заголовки. Отправили запрос на логаут - переадресовали на страницу удаления сессии, а оттуда уже на страницу авторизации. Ну или аяксом, например, удалили сессию, а потом отправили на страницу авторизации.

Answer (score -1):

```
onclick="function(){
var req = new XMLHttpRequest;
req.open('POST','/path/destroy.php');
req.send(null);
}"
```

А уже в сам php файл вставьте свой код.

Comment: Не советуйте делать оторванные файлы от логики кода. Без какой-либо защиты.